# Search detection on Tor browser

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity, security, configuration, windows

Once you close your Tor browser, is there any way to detect what you searched for on your computer at a later date?

Answer (score 1):

The Tor Browser will delete all "private" data when it's closed. So when you close it you won't be able to restore your search history.

However as [uwotm8](https://tor.stackexchange.com/users/3249/uwotm8) wrote, when someone got access to your machine, those information can be extracted.

Answer (score 0):

It depends very much on the computer you are using and if it is trustworthy. Malware or bad actor with administrative privileges may very well be able to record your Tor traffic before it's encrypted.